# HttpURLConnection -->get the old version web page

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpurlconnection

I use method 'setProperty' of Java HttpURLConnection to crawl web pages.

I have set 'User-agent' ,but I got the old version web pages of the website

I could get access to the new version by Chrome

by my phone I got the old version

Do you have some advice or some possible solution to get the new version by Java HttpURLConnection?

Thank you so much!

code:

```
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)             AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", ENCODE);
            conn.setRequestProperty("contentType", ENCODE);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.connect();
```

Comment: Your title should not be a Google search. It should be a very short description of your problem. In addition, you'll want to have someone else reread that and fix all of the errors, since this is barely understandable as it is. Lastly, please remember to do a bit of Googling around and whatnot first, before asking here. If you already have, and found nothing, it's generally better to say that so people like me don't assume you haven't.

Comment: Yeah,it is been a little rush last night, I do something in a really unfamiliar area for me. So I ask this question here to see if I could get some useful messages and at the meantime I do more Googling.....  Thank you for the tips. For a fresh hand, I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i passed web site url as www.example.com to HttpURLConnection. This returns old web page. But in Chrome, i get new version of web site. Then i noticed that the url in Chrome is http://example.com. There is no www. This returns the new version of web site. When i changed the url that i pass to HttpURLConnection, it get the new version of web site.